# How to set a value in the tkinter slider.set method?

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

I am trying to simulate a stellar system. I aim to manipulate the parameters via slider widgets,  see the (reduced) code below. The slider widget in my code accepts a new value for the sun mass, which was set via a StellarSys instance. However the slider.set method fails with TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Does somebody have a solution or can explain what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math     

class Space(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, size, bg=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        frame = tk.Frame(self, border=5)
        frame.pack()
        self.width, self.height = size
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=self.width,height=self.height,
                                borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg=bg)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.bodies = None

    def place_bodies(self):
        for body in self.bodies:
            x1, y1 = int(body.loc[0]-body.size/2.0),int(body.loc[1]-body.size/2.0) 
            x2, y2 = x1 + body.size, y1 + body.size
            body.tk_id = self.canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=body.color)

class SpaceBody:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name  = kwargs['name']
        self.size  = kwargs['size']
        self.mass  = kwargs['mass']
        self.loc   = kwargs['loc']
        self.speed = kwargs['speed']
        self.color = kwargs['color']
        self.dxdy  = (0,0)
        self.tk_id = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"\n{self.name} is {self.color}"

class Dashboard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, bg=None):    
        super().__init__(master)
        frame = tk.Frame(self, border=5, bg=bg)
        frame.pack()
        sun_frame=tk.Frame(frame)
        sun_frame.grid(row=1)
        w, h = 15, 3

        tk.Label(sun_frame, text = '').grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(sun_frame, text = 'SUN MASS').grid(row=1)
        self.sun_mass = tk.Scale(sun_frame, from_=0, to=1000, orient='horizontal')
        self.sun_mass.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.update)
#        self.sun_mass.set(500) # this works
        self.sun_mass.set(space.bodies[0].mass) # This doesn't work
        self.sun_mass.grid(row=2)

    def update(self, event):
        space.bodies[0].mass = self.sun_mass.get()
        print(space.bodies[0].mass)


class StellarSys:
    def __init__(self):
        sun   = SpaceBody(name='Sun',  size=30, mass=500, loc=(500,400),speed=(0, 0), color='yellow')
        earth = SpaceBody(name='Earth',size=15, mass=1,  loc=(500,200),speed=(15,0), color='green')
        space.bodies = [sun, earth]
        space.place_bodies()
               
# MAIN
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('UNIVERSE')
size = (1000, 800)
space = Space(root, size, bg='black')
space.grid(row=0, column = 0,sticky="nsew")
dashboard = Dashboard(root)
dashboard.grid(row=0, column = 1,sticky="nsew")
stellarsys = StellarSys()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `self.bodies` to `None`, and then try to subscript that value. As the error says, you can't use subscripts on a value of `None`.

You need to rework your logic so that `self.bodies` is a non-empty list before trying to reference an item in the list.